# Google Sheets Query: Bring data by date in cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to query a google sheet by date. I have done some research and learned I need to convert to `TEXT` format so that I can run the comparison, but I am not able to get the syntax correctly:

```
=query('SheetName'!$A2:$S, "select A Where O=date'"&TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&)
```

Could you give me some guidance?

Some more info: in my query, B2 is a valid date in date format. Column O has some cells that are text strings and others that are valid dates; I have set the format of the entire column to "Date".

Here is a link to a simple example, feel free to play around with the query: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O4ms9ufvZ_CRLl_LG45hksjRoOJtv0XexbfjCLqFW4I/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax should be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(SheetName!$A2:$S),
 "select Col16 where Col15 = '"&TO_TEXT(DATEVALUE(B2))&"'"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thank you. the query is OK now (no error), but it only returns column headers, not content. I am sure it should be returning a bunch of records.

Comment: are those records valid numbers only? if so then try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT('SheetName'!$A2:$S), "select Col1 where Col15 = date '"&TEXT(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0))`

Comment: or perhaps: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({TO_TEXT('SheetName'!$A2:$A),'SheetName'!$B2:$S}, "select Col1 where Col15 = date '"&TEXT(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0))`

Comment: Thanks, but no luck with those. Some more info: in my query, B2 is a valid date in date format. Column O has some cells that are text strings and others that are valid dates. I have set the format of the entire column to "date".

Comment: I added a URL with a small sample that allows you to play around with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192315/discussion-between-quelquecosa-and-player0).

Answer (score 0):

See if this works?

```
=filter('SheetName'!A3:A, 'SheetName'!O3:O=B2)
```